# how to run call some Javascript code with jQuery as soon as element loads to page by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to assign some attributes to some html tags as soon as they load to the page by Ajax, but I don't want to write any Javascript in my page. foe example I have the the html like below:(remember that this comes via ajax, not on page load)

```
<div data-something="true">
 something here
</div>
```

and I want to have something like this which is saved to a .js file: (this doesn't work)

```
$('body').on('load', '[data-something]', function(){  
       //do something 
});
```

but I do NOT want to have like this in one page :

```
<div data-something="true">
 something here
</div>

<script>
   $(function(){
        //do something
   });
</script>
```

is there anyway to do so? to trigger the event as soon as the element being loaded?

Comment: Then source the Javascript file in a script tag.  What is the problem with that?  `<script src='my_js_file.js'></script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, put it in the success of the ajax call.

```
$("someelemnt").load("somepage.html",function(){
    // do something.
});
```

do not use script tags on a page that you are loading via ajax, they'll usually get executed before the html is appended to the page.

Comment: I missed the bit about this being AJAX. L2Read

Comment: @crush In your defense, it is a little hard to see the way it wraps to the next line, :-P

Comment: I think my real problem is that I read the code then start assuming I know what the person is asking...lol