# Transfer and trigger javascript code by ajax call with jsf

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, callback

I have some jsf-code with a tag that is re-rendered by an ajax call. It contains something like

```
<h:outputScript>alert("Gotcha")</h:outputScript>
```

but this is only executed on first load, not on an ajax induced partial render.

This is but a minimal example, what I'm really trying to do is to trigger some server-generated javascript right after the ajax-call has returned, something like

```
<h:outputScript>#{scriptBean.getScript()}</h:outputScript>
```

I've seen [calling .trigger("click") that is in javascript code returned from an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29157206/4142984), [Asynchronize ajax calls and javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22437251/4142984), [how to run call some Javascript code with jQuery as soon as element loads to page by Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14285383/4142984) and [Running javascript code called by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242240/4142984), but neither questions nor answers look like they address my question, least not without some additional hint or explanation.

And because I want to keep things small and simple, and because I could avoid anything above jsf:core (mostly), I'd prefer solutions that avoid using yafl (== yet another fancy library).

Edit: as for the comment from @BalusC I post more context:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="${cc.attrs.imgId}" styleClass="small" onchange="alert('Gotcha0');">
        <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{mBean.register}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{mBean.init}" />
        <f:attribute name="flav" value="#{cc.attrs.flav}" />
        <h:graphicImage width="${cc.attrs.width}" id="${cc.attrs.imgId}"
            onclick="if (event.isTrusted) this.nextSibling.value=mods(event);"
            onmouseover="aa=this.id" alt="not found"
            onchange="alert('Gotcha1');"
            value="images/img?#{cc.attrs.flav}=#{mBean.getNextCount()}&amp;imgId=#{cc.attrs.imgId}">
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"
                onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { 
                console.log('HiHo'+data.responseCode+'\n\n'+ data.responseText+'\n\n'+data.responseXML);
                me=window.document.getElementById('#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}');
                me.nextSibling.nextSibling.value=0;
                me.nextSibling.value=0;
                me.myfunc=function(event)
                 {
                 console.log('keyCode='+event.keyCode+' mods='+mods(event)+'/'+this.nextSibling.id);
                    this.nextSibling.value=mods(event);
                    this.nextSibling.nextSibling.value=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                    this.click();
                 }; }; }"
                listener="#{mBean.handleEvent}" render="@this">
            </f:ajax>
        </h:graphicImage>
        <h:inputHidden id="m" value="#{mBean.keyX}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="k" value="#{mBean.key}" />
    </h:form>
    <h:outputScript>alert("Gotcha2")</h:outputScript>
    <h:outputScript>var i=0;window.document.getElementById('#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}').myfunc=function(event)
     {
     aa='#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}:#{cc.attrs.imgId}';
     this.nextSibling.value=mods(event);
     this.nextSibling.nextSibling.value=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
     this.click();
     };
     </h:outputScript>
</composite:implementation>
```

"Gotcha2" shows up only at load time, once for each instance of the composite, but not when the component is re-rendered via ajax calls.

"Gotcha0" and "Gotcha1" are completely ignored.

The "HiHo" shows up for every ajax-call on the component, but I would like the function to fire only when the component is *rendered*, which is a subtle difference, because I might manipulate the render-list on server side, like

```
  private void addToRenderMap(String obj) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Collection<String> renderIds = context.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds();
    renderIds.add(obj);
  }
```

or even remove the calling component from the list. 
(For example, for keypress "i", I want to only show image information in some other component and avoid unnecessary re-sending of the image data.)

Edit2: I see that **onchange** really is more a *onvaluechange* for fields that take input, so it's not a big surprise that this part of the code is ignored.

Comment: @BalusC you got me there, thanks for the hint. NO, obviously this would only render the h:form. There was a reason, though, to put those things outside of the form, but I can't remember. Will do some experimentation.

Comment: @BalusC right you are, thanks a lot. when I put the h:outputScript just before the end of the h:graphicImage, it works! Should I delete the question?

Comment: @BalusC, sad, so this is only working by accident. So what is the right way to do it????